# Google AppEngine: 502 Bad Gateway From Deploying Flask App

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debugging, flask

I'm experiencing so much trouble launch my application from the remote server after deploying it to Google AppEngine. I've looked up similar questions and tried to apply the suggested fixes, but still no success - I keep getting that 502 Bad Gateway Issue. Could someone please advise?

Folder structure is like this:

> **directory: cross_sell_dash/**
>   app.yml
>   database.py
>   Dockerfile
>   gcp-sa-creds.json
>   main.py
>   requirements.txt

**app.yml**

```
entrypoint: "gunicorn --bind:$PORT main:app"
env: flex
runtime: custom
```

**main.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/call/<function_name>/search/", methods=["GET"])
def callFunction(function_name: str):
    user_id = request.args.get('user_id')
    savm_id = request.args.get('savm_id')
    business_sub_entity = request.args.get('business_sub_entity')
    user_comments = request.args.get('user_comments')
    user_approval = request.args.get('user_approval')
    functionToCall = getattr(Database(), function_name)
    return str(functionToCall(user_id, savm_id, business_sub_entity, user_comments, user_approval))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3-onbuild

RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn","--bind=0.0.0.0:8080","main:app"]
```

Comment: Hey, does this work locally? It only fails on GAE? Could you please post your requirements.txt also? Could you explain why are you using python:3-onbuild instead of just python3? Is your VM instance running correctly? Bad gateways normally happen when the application isn't capable of answering the request. (probably never initalized or crashed)

Let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Remove the `entrypoint` in app.yaml
- Update `Dockerfile` as follows

```
FROM python:3-onbuild

RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "--bind=0.0.0.0:8080", "main:app"]
```

Comment: Please, let me know how I can include information of the Dockerfile to be applied while installation using this command: gcloud app deploy; apparently, it does not take into account the info within Dockerfile.